# How can I return DOM content without HTML tags?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm using the following function to remove tags and its content from user submitted comments:

```
function remove_html_element($tag,$content){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
    foreach ($xpath->query('//'.$tag) as $node) {
        $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

The problem is that the returned content is wrapped in HTML `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC (...)`.

How can I return the content without any additional tags?

Comment: i would do that by playing with `strpos/substr` for getting the `<body>` contents and then calling `strip_tags` on it. DOM parsers will lose a lot of time parsing/making arrays which is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove tags from text, `DOMDocument` is an extraordinarily heavyweight way of doing that. Is there some reason that [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) won't suffice?

Comment: No, because then you are just stripping the tags and not the content in between.